# How to write component repeater

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

for example, there is such an array:

```
let array = [ { name: "QWE" }, { name: "ASD" } ]
```

I have to write a Repeater component that will output this data in a loop.
Here is an example of using this component:

```
<Repeater data={array}>
    <h1>{data.name}</h1>
</Repeater>
```

I can write anything inside this component
but the data must be placed each in its place

the output should be

```
<h1>QWE</h1><h1>ASD</h1>
```

I received the data, made a cycle in the render, but how to transfer this data inside this.props.children

I use react-jsx-parser. and because of this, I cannot use the function, and such answers will not work

```
data => (<h1 key = {data.key}>{data.name}</h1>)
```

https://github.com/Abdubek/CustomComponent here is the minimum project

Comment: Use a function as the child that returns a component given a single datum. Then `Array#map` with that function in the parent: `this.props.data.map(this.props.children)`

Comment: Thanks for answering. that's what i immediately did. but I want to give anything as a child component, for example <span> {data.text} </ span> or <button> {data.text} </ button> and it should output a span or button

Comment: @AbdubekZholay `.map` allows you to do this - `array.map(x => <h1>{x.name}</h1>)` or `array.map(x => <button>{x.name}</button>)`

Comment: @user633183 but react-jsx-parser does not allow

Comment: @AbdubekZholay yes it does - there's some other problem with your environment if it's not compiling. The provided answer even includes a functioning demo.

Comment: @user633183 The answer given does not use react-jsx-parser. its properties do not allow me to do this

Comment: @AbdubekZholay you don't need react-jsx-parser to do this

Comment: @user633183 i need react-jsx-parser need for another purpose. My layout comes in the form of a string. and I have to parse this string to display

Answer (score -1):

If you use child function, you can render custom child component that will be returned from the function. You should also pass `key` prop because of `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` warning. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sm6f0v8a/1/) is example.

```
const data = [{ name: 'QWE' }, { name: 'ASD' }]

const Repeater = ({ children, data }) => (
    data.map((itemData, i) => (
        children({ ...itemData, key: i })
    ))
)

const Root = () => (
  <Repeater data={data}>
    {data => (
      <h1 key={data.key}>
          {data.name}
      </h1>
    )}
  </Repeater>
)


ReactDOM.render(
  <Root />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. it is a pity that I can not write: {data => (
      <h1 key={data.key}>
          {data.name}
      </h1>
    )}
react-jsx-parser does not allow

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. The repeated component should be defined as its own component, and the parent should simply use `this.props.data.map(d => SeparateComponent(d))`